# Extract X number of minutes from the current time from a logfile

Tags: text-processing, awk, logs

I have a logfile with the following timestamp format

```
2016-06-02 13:59:58.069
```

The log I am working with spans about an hour.

```
2016-06-02 13:05:06.144
2016-06-02 13:05:06.144
2016-06-02 13:05:06.160
2016-06-02 13:05:06.160
2016-06-02 13:05:06.176
2016-06-02 13:05:06.177
.
.
.
.
2016-06-02 14:05:03.033
2016-06-02 14:05:03.034
2016-06-02 14:05:03.034
2016-06-02 14:05:03.084
2016-06-02 14:05:03.096
2016-06-02 14:05:03.112
```

When I try to use awk to extract out the last 10 minutes I still get the whole file.

```
awk -vDate=`date -d'now-10 minutes' +%Y/%m/%d:%H:%M:%S` '$1,$2 >   Date {print Date, $0}' logfile.log | less
```

Awk output:

```
2016/06/02:08:57:35 2016-06-02 13:05:06.144
. 
.
.
2016/06/02:08:57:35 2016-06-02 14:08:05.214
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your input format is "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" but your Date variable is "YYYY/MM/DD:hh:mm:ss" - totally different and so the inequality doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
awk -vDate="`date -d'TZ="UTC" now-10 minutes' +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N'`" '$1" "$2 > Date {print Date, $0}'
```

In the pattern `$1,$2 > Date`, the comma doesn't mean "join these fields" like it does in the output; instead, it means the pattern is a [record range](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ranges.html).  `$1` is a non-empty string, which is always `true`, so the match starts immediately.  You need to put a literal space there to join the fields before comparing: `$1" "$2`

Next, you can see in your example output that you were setting `Date` to "2016/06/02:...", while the logs used "2016-06-02 ...".  As you are comparing date *strings*, and `/` is later than `-` in ASCII, the test would never succeed.  Changing the string format to match exactly (with some added quoting to protect it from the shell) means only the digits will differ.

**Edit:**
Your logfile timestamps are a few hours later than what `date -d'now-10 minutes'` shows.  You can tell `date` to use the relevant timezone  either with an environment variable (`TZ=UTC awk ...`) or inside the date string `'TZ="UTC" now...'`.  If it's not `UTC`, pick the right one from [the complete list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Comment: Its still not working using your updated command. I'm still getting the entire file.

Comment: @user53029 I've put back the `print Date, $0` output like you had it - could you show one of the lines that was output but shouldn't be?

Comment: 2016-06-02 13:40:06.989...this is the first line output when I run the command and redirect to an output file. I ran awk -vDate="`date -d'now-10 minutes' +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N'`" '$1" "$2 > Date {print}' logfile.log > tmp.bak && mv -f tmp.bak logfile_last10. I went back to using only > Date {print}' because it made no difference the other way. I also redirected to a tmp location and moved the contents of that location into a file that should only contain the last 10 minutes.

Comment: I also just | less'ed the actual file and it had the same output.

Comment: @user53029 I meant for you to post the output line that contains both the original timestamp, and the value of `Date` awk is comparing it to, so I can work out whether it's the `date` or `awk` part that is going wrong.  Also, could you mention the versions of `date` and `awk`?

Comment: 2016-06-02 10:56:37.005 2016-06-02 13:40:06.989. GNU Awk 3.1.7 and date (GNU coreutils) 8.4. The first date in the row is the awk date, second is the original timestamp. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I see the problem 10:56:37 *is* before 13:40:06 .  `date` is running in one timezone, and your logfile in another.  Which one is right for you?

Comment: I need to go with whats in the logfile. Which is UTC+5 I believe. I suppose they are both "right" so to speak but saying I need to be able to go back 10 minutes in a log that uses UTC is more accurate.

Comment: Are you saying put TZ=UTC in at the prompt then run the awk script?

Comment: Still not working whether I set the shell to UTC or run it in the command. I still get the entire file as output. This should not be this difficult.

Comment: Its even doing it in /var/log/messages, which is in CST.

Comment: I got both tz forms wrong on the previous attempt :( Please try again

Comment: Still the same. First line of output - 2016-06-02 08:21:00.894 2016-06-02 16:38:02.886. Last line of output - 2016-06-02 08:21:00.894 2016-06-02 18:31:12.351.

Comment: That's even further in the past.  So you've successfully changed `date`'s timezone, but you're going to have to work out the right time zone for yourself, by watching the new additions to the logfile as they come in.

Answer (score 1):

Using a different approach. I get the vDate, `grep` to obtain the line number and `tail` the file from that line number :

```
vDate=`date -d'now-10 minutes' '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'` 
line=`grep  -n "$vDate" logfile.log | head -1  | cut -d: -f1`
tail -n +${line} logfile.log
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` can print the lines of a text in a section with `start_pattern` and `end_pattern`, use the following syntax:

```
$ awk '/start_pattern/, /end _pattern/' filename
```

quote from *Linux Shell Scripting Cookbook*.

So, you can do it like this:

```
awk '/2016-06-02 13:55/, /2016-06-02 14:05/' logfile`
```

You could also writing this to the script file if you want:

```
START=`date --date='now-10 minutes' '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'`
END=`date --date='now' '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'`
awk "/$START/, /$END/" logfile
```

Comment: Yes but this will only work if the file contains at least one line that matches exactly the start of range e.g. `2016-06-02 13:55`. If it doesn't, e.g. if nothing was logged at `13:55` and it only has `13:54` and `13:56` your command won't print anything.